# I am trying to install ROS Jade from source in debian jessie. I get the following error "Failed to process package 'pcl_conversions'"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read somewhere that ros has its own version of PCL which it downloads and install. Now the error I get is following:

```
By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
  CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" with any of
  the following names:

    PCLConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake
```

As far as I know this means that the package PCL doesn't exists. This makes not much sense to me as ROS must have downloaded and installed it. I am stuck at this point.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222814/i-am-trying-to-install-ros-jade-from-source-in-debian-jessie.-i-get-the-following-error-%22failed-to-process-package-%27pcl_conversions%27%22/) by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved this issue. I had to install libpcl-dev package. After installing it the issue was resolved.

---

Originally posted by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) with karma: 56 on 2015-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1